# Trying to make an ordering menu, and everything works but I'm not sure how to actually work out a total

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Menu from './components/Menu.js';
import Items from './components/Items.js';
import Interface from './components/Interface.js';
import Total from './components/Total.js';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Coffee Shop</h1>
      <div className="menu-container">
        <Menu source="./images/menu.png"/>
        <div className="order">
          <div className="menu-list">
            <Items item="Latte: £2.20"/>
            <Items item="Espresso: £2.70"/>
            <Items item="Macchiato: £3.40"/>
          </div>
          <div className ="interface">
            <Interface/>
            <Interface/>
            <Interface/>
            <Total/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Interface.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Interface = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const decrease = () => {
        if (counter > 0) {
            setCounter(count => count - 1);
        }
    };
    const increase = () => {
        setCounter(count => count + 1);
    };
    const reset = () => {
        setCounter(0);
    };
    
    return (
    <div id="interface-item">
        <button id="interface-button" onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        <button id="interface-button" onClick={increase}>+</button>
        <span id="interface-counter">{counter}</span>
        <button id="interface-button" onClick={reset}>x</button>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Interface;
```

Total.js:

```
const Total = (props) => {
    return (
        <span id="total">Total: £0.00</span>
    )
}

export default Total;
```

I need to assign a price to each instance of Interface, pull the counter from it and multiply it, adding them all together and displaying the total. I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Right now you _can't_ get the total, because the values only exist inside the Interface elements. [Lift the state up.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it with my code, though. The code on the site you sent me looks very different to what I'm doing. I've only been doing this a day so I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to implement a basic cart you can do something like this

```
const your_menu = [
  {
    id: 'someId',
    name: 'Latte',
    price: 2.21
  },
  {
    id: 'someId',
    name: 'Espresso',
    price: 2.72
  },
]

function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([])
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0)
  // These are the functions in your Interface file

  // First to add items to the cart

  const add = (name) => { // Here i suggest you use id instead of name
    for(const item in your_menu){
      if(your_menu[item].name === name){
        setCart(items => [...items, your_menu[item]])

      }

    }

  }

// To remove items from your cart. There are better ways to do this but this simply just removes an item at a clicked index nothing complex.

   const remove = (index) => { // This may not be the most accurate way to remove items from an array, but you can look that up
    setCart(cart.slice(0, index).concat(cart.slice(index + 1)))

  }

  const clear = () => {
    setCart([])
  }


// This will monitor the cart and calculate the total of the items in it
React.useEffect(() => {
  let items_total = 0
  cart.forEach(item => {
    items_total += item.price
  })
  setTotal(items_total)
},[cart])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Coffee Shop</h1>
      {
        your_menu.map((coffee, index) => {
          return(
            <div  key={coffee + index}>
             <div onClick={() => {
              add(coffee.name)
            }}>
              <h2>{coffee.name}</h2>
              <p>{coffee.price}</p>
            </div>


            <hr />
            </div>


          )
        })
      }

<>
      <h1>This is the cart</h1>
        {
          cart.map((items,index) => {
            return(
              <div key={items + index}>
                <h2>{items.name} - {items.price}</h2>
                <div onClick={() => {
                  remove(index)
                }}>
              <h1 style={{color: "#ff0000"}}>Click to Delete</h1>
            </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </>

      <>
        <h1>Your Total will go here</h1>
        <h2>{total}</div>
      </>
    </div>

  );
  }

export default App;
```

This is split into 3 sections `menu`, `cart` and `total`

I hope it helps you understand how to implement a shopping cart well that's what I got from your question.